# Listview shows junk value

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-widget

Hi i'm doing sample project, in that i had an issue like listitem shows some junk value. Don't know how to solve. Can any one help me out.

This is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView app_List;
private ArrayList<AppInfo> infoList;
private ArrayAdapter<AppInfo> adpt;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    app_List = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    infoList = getListOfUserInstalledApps();
    }

   private ArrayList<AppInfo> getListOfUserInstalledApps() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    System.out.println("No. of applications installed on the device: "+apps.size());
    ArrayList<AppInfo> infoList1 = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
    for(int i=0;i<apps.size();i++) {        
        PackageInfo p = apps.get(i);        
        /*if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {      
            continue ;        }*/

        AppInfo info = new AppInfo();
        //info.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        info.pname = p.packageName;
        System.out.println("application name: "+info.pname);
        //info.pname = p.packageName;
        infoList1.add(info);

    }
    return infoList1;
}
static class AppInfo {
    //private String appname = "";    
    private String pname = "";    
    //private String versionName = "";    
    //private int versionCode = 0;    
    //private Drawable icon;

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    adpt =  new ArrayAdapter<AppInfo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, infoList);
    app_List.setAdapter(adpt);

}
}
```

refer screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Axi.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `ListView` is showing is not junk but a human representation of the reference of the object `AppInfo`.  You have two ways to fix your issue. You can pass an `ArrayList<String>` instead of  `ArrayList<AppInfo>` to the `ArrayAdapter`, or override `getView` from the `ArrayAdapter`.

**Edit**

As `@Luksprog` suggested (see his comment below) you can also override `AppInfo.toString()` in order to return `pname`

Comment: *You have two ways to fix your issue* - or the third easier way, of overriding the `toString()` method for the `AppInfo` class to return the target value(the *pname* I'm assuming).

Comment: Beware! @toString() is not meant to give a text for user interfaces. It should give human readable information about the object. toString is for logging and debugging

Comment: @verbose-mode Tell that to the `ArrayAdapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot shows the toString value of each of your AppInfo objects. AppInfo should override toString to display the structure as the string you want.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html